Understanding the proof of Theorem 10.2 in Montgomery & Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory
In Theorem 10.2 of the book of Montgomery & Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory there are two claims comes without any explanation:
1- For $0 < u < \infty$, $(u + a)^{s−1} ≪ |a|^{σ−1}$ uniformly for $ℜa ≥ 0, |a| ≥ ε > 0$, and $|σ| ≤ C$. How is this true? For example, $σ−1 > 0$ seems a contradiction for the statement.
2- The above statement implies: $n^{-s} \Gamma(s/2, πn^2z) ≪ n^{-2}$ uniformly for $ℜz ≥ 0, |z| ≥ ε, |s| ≤ C$. How $n^{-s} \Gamma(s/2, πn^2z) ≪ n^{-2}$ is true, for the mentioned conditions? ( $\Gamma(s/2, πn^2z)$ is the incomplete Gamma function).

What is the relation between $s$ and $\sigma$? Is $\sigma = Re(s)$?

@RaulFernandesHorta, yes typical notation

The first statement is wrong, but it does not affect what comes afterwards. Observe that when $s=\sigma+it$, there is
$$
\Re[(s-1)\log(u+a)]=(\sigma-1)\log|u+a|-t\arg(u+a)
$$
Since $|s|\le C$, we have $|t|\le C$ and $|\arg(u+a)|<\pi/2$, so
\begin{align}
\Re[(s-1)\log(u+a)]
&=(\sigma-1)\log|u+a|+O(1), \\
&=(\sigma-1)\log|a|+(\sigma-1)\log\left(1+\frac u{|a|}\right)+O(1). \\
&\le(\sigma-1)\log|a|+(C-1)\log(1+u\varepsilon^{-1})+O(1) \\
&\le(\sigma-1)\log|a|+C_1\log u
\end{align}
for some fixed $C_1>0$. This indicates that
$$
|\Gamma(s,a)|\le|a|^{\sigma-1}\int_0^\infty u^{C_1}e^{-u}\mathrm du\ll|a|^{\sigma-1},
$$
so we have
$$
n^{-s}\Gamma(s/2,\pi n^2z)\ll n^{-\sigma}|\pi n^2z|^{\frac\sigma2-1}\ll n^{-2},
$$
provided that $\Re(z)\ge0$, $|z|\ge\varepsilon$, and $|s|\le C$.
